# Calling external API asynchronously, rails on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, heroku

In my rails/heroku web app, I make a call to an external API, (the json result is used in the view).  Currently that call is in a controller, but I am having issues with the external source being very slow, causing the page to load slow, or even time-out.  I don't think I can use regular jquery/js/ajax because **the API call contains my private API key. How can I make this call asynchronously?**

1) Can I make the call in the controller asynchronous, or
 2) Can I hide my key when making a call from the view, or
 3) Is there a better way of handling this?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider adding another route to proxy the long request.  From your view, use AJAX to load that route and add the result to the DOM when it returns.  Until that time, you can display a fancy *spinner* gif or something like *loading...*

For example

#### routes.rb

```
...
get '/long_calls/show' => 'long_calls#show'
get '/long_calls/show2' => 'long_calls#show2'
...
```

#### long_calls_controller.rb

```
class LongCallsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @message = "*Please Wait*"
  end

  def show2
    @message = LongCall.thing_that_takes_a_long_time
  end
end
```

#### views/long_calls/show.html.erb

```
<script>
  $(function) {
    $.get("show2");
  }
</script>
<div id='lazyload'>
  <%= @message %>
</div>
```

#### views/long_calls/show2.js.erb

```
$("#lazyload").html("<% escape_javascript @message %>");
```

Comment: Hey that's a good idea.  The server would still block on long api calls, but I suppose that's a different problem.

Comment: You could also use the daemon that watches the database for new "jobs" that it processes.  When the process is complete, it updates a field in the table indicating that the job is "complete".  Using AJAX, your page could poll the server every second or so until it gets the "complete" data.

Comment: Troy could you offer an example of what "adding another route to proxy the long request" might mean? 

I have a very similar problem making large requests to a Salesforce instance but am slightly stumped as to how to resolve it.